# Can't install express because npm install express error

Tags: express, npm, npm-install

I'm receiving the following errors when trying to install `express`:

1. `npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE`
2. `npm ERR! errno ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE`
3. `npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line`

Comment: What its the command you run? Which version of npm you have? Is it only happens for express or other packages?

Comment: yes,i run on command   npm version 6.10.0

Answer (score 6):

I also had a problem like that... and looking around for various solutions on the internet I tried a few of these:

- Try `npm install` to another repository
- Try install another version of [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- `npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

If the above method still fails. You can try these:

1. Uninstall nodejs from Programs & Features with the uninstaller.
2. Delete these files:

   - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs`
   - `C:\Program Files\Nodejs`
   - `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm`
   - `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`
   - `C:\Users\{User}\.npmrc` (and possibly check for that without the `.` prefix too)
3. Reboot, for good measure
4. Try too install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) again
5. Try too `nmp install` to destination repository

Good luck... with what I mentioned above, I was able to solve the problem with my setup.

Comment: It's good to know that uninstalling works, but it is usually a better solution to fix the specific problem, both for the user and the team who owns the software.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue and based on the error message, I noticed the certificate (.crt) and the private key (.pem) files I have in the ssl folder needed to have this lines before the start and at the end of the key contents:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Your key contents go here for .pem file

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

The same is required for the certificate file and missing either generates the same error:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Your certificate contents go here for .crt file

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Answer (score 2):

## Do the following :

### Delete the following mention

- *npm cache clean -f*
- C:\User\user\appdata\roaming\npm-cache
- C:\User\user\appdata\roaming\npm
- C:\User\user\appdata\Local\Temp
- C:\programefile\nodejs
- delete node version manager (nvm) is their
- type *where node* on cmd if it shows node js path means node js is properly not uninstalled
- delete node js and npm  path from environment variable
- go to this much address *C:\User\user* them right click on empty space and go to property and tick on hidden in order to get .npmrc file and delete all reated to it
- delete other version of node js if installed

#### after doing this much restart your pc and then install new latest  recommended version of node js. After installed the node js run *node -v* to check version you installed and *npm -v* for npm version

Answer (score 0):

Type this command

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

and after that try again

```
npm install express
```

as per this [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10897) it is a certificate related problem

Comment: it be inefficient

Comment: What does "inefficient" mean in this context?

Answer (score 0):

This process worked for me:

1. Setting the registry with: npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
2. Retrying the install with  npm install express

Answer (score 0):

Type this commands:

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ 
and after that try again
npx create-react-app app_name
```

it's work for me