# Can't install npm packages in expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, node-modules, npm-install

Getting this error while installing node modules in expo project.tried uninstalling/reinstalling Node.js and expo. How to resolve this?

I'm receiving this error when in run npm install in expo project. Any solution?

npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-24T04_23_35_007Z-debug.log

```
1212 silly saveTree +-- react-navigation@4.3.9
1212 silly saveTree +-- react@16.9.0
1212 silly saveTree +-- redux@4.0.5
1212 silly saveTree `-- yarn@1.22.4
1213 verbose stack Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
1213 verbose stack     at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:149:17)
1213 verbose stack     at Object.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1588:48)
1213 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createConnection (https.js:130:22)
1213 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createSocket (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agentkeepalive\lib\_http_agent.js:265:26)
1213 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createSocket (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agentkeepalive\lib\agent.js:77:11)
1213 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.addRequest (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agentkeepalive\lib\_http_agent.js:239:10)
1213 verbose stack     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:296:16)
1213 verbose stack     at request (https.js:314:10)
1213 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:54:17
1213 verbose stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
1213 verbose stack     at fetch (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:41:10)
1213 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js:332:14
1213 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-retry\index.js:29:24
1214 verbose cwd D:\React\customer-app
1215 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
1216 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
1217 verbose node v12.18.0
1218 verbose npm  v6.14.5
1219 error code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
1220 error error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
1221 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: attach more log for this error. it may be because of syntax error in your code or conflict in packages that you import and use in your project.

Comment: Hi, added more log files now. please help me to resolve this error

Comment: Same solution as given in this thread... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194920/cant-install-express-because-npm-install-express-error/57195189#57195189

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

`npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Then, try running `npm install`